# Homebrew OS X OpenCV - looking for dylib when running on another Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, homebrew

I have a cross platform (Windows + Mac) application, built with QT and C++ libraries, which uses OpenCV. I had previously used an OpenCV version downloaded and compiled on the Mac, but decided to try to use the homebrew version to simplify installation on dev machines.

I did `brew install opencv --with-contrib` and `brew link opencv`, and managed to get the program to link and run with the libraries from /usr/local/lib.

Problem is, when I install it on another Mac, the program crashes when I try to run it, saying: `Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.1/lib/libIex-2_2.23.dylib`.

I'm not sure what to do. I'm not a Mac expert, and certainly no Homebrew expert. Should I go back to compiling OpenCV myself, or can this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the dependent libraries into your application package.

Comment: (It's probably a dynamic vs. static linking issue, so questions are: can I get static versions of the libs through homebrew, and if not, can I just put the dylibs from OpenCV alongside the executable, and how do I know which ones I need?)

Comment: You can certainly build static versions of OpenCV. I use CMake and Hunter to do this as it takes a lot of the pain away: https://github.com/ruslo/hunter

Comment: Thanks, Richard. Hunter sounds interesting, though it also sounds like something that'd take a bit of reading to get working. Any quick tips (or code) to get and make static OpenCV with it?

Comment: here's a sandbox I was playing in with my son - it shows basic use of hunter and polly (toolchains). 
You can browse available packages here: https://github.com/hunter-packages

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, but I solved it. homebrew installed latest opencv and dependencies. openexr and ilmbase also installed latest version. but opencv.jar refered specific version of library.(ex libIex-2_2.23.dylib)
So, you'd install ilmbase version 2.2.X. and than solve library issue.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ilmbase.rb

This link is ilmbase install Formula. You can ckeckout v.2.2 Formula commit.
And than uninstall & re-install ilmbase v.2.2.